# It is updated but it say Pleaseupdate @react-navigation/bottom-tabs, @react-navigation/stack and @react-navigation/drawer to version 5.10.0 or above

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, npm-install

I am new at react-native. I am trying to run a program with expo but
I am getting this Yellow error

'It appears that you are using old version of react-navigation library. Please update @react-navigation/bottom-tabs, @react-navigation/stack and @react-navigation/drawer to version 5.10.0 or above to take full advantage of new functionality added to react-native-screens'

This is my package.json file. I don't know why but i can see it in here but somehow it can't seen by program.

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "expo": "^43.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.13.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.5.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

what should i do?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the node modules and reinstall everything ?

Like ```rm -rf node_modules```

Comment: its just warning not error when error accurse its show in red

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall these modules and re-install it.

Or try to add those modules with specific versions.
like as `npm i @react-navigation/drawer@5.10.0`